# Is testing/validation necessary when the model is not going to be used on new data?

Tags: validation, importance

I am doing an analysis on data where each row is a state, trying to predict energy consumption per capita from various other features. I am currently using LOOCV but I realized, what is the point of validating if I am making the model to interpret which features have the largest effect on energy consumption? Should I still be worried about overfitting, or does it not matter since I don't need the model to generalize to new data?

Additionally, I want to know if each feature has a positive or negative effect. I know this can be done with ridge regression just by looking at the coefficients, but what if I were to use a tree ensemble instead (to get 0 training error)? I can see the magnitude of importance with the sklearn attribute feature_importances_, but what about the directional effect on energy consumption?

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis if not to predict?  It sounds like you want to measure associations between outcomes and variables, which sounds a lot like statistical inference.  In such a case, biased models like ridge regression are not a good idea.  Can you edit your question with more information on your goals and data?

Comment: If you want zero training error and will not be using the model to make predictions, why not just have the model be $\hat y = y?$ (I realize this is ridiculous. Why it is ridiculous for your purposes will be informative.)

Comment: @DemetriPananos the goal is to see which socioeconomic features have a positive impact on energy consumption and which have a negative impact and to what degree. Each data point is a state (for only 51 data points including D.C.), and features include income, race, politics, education, etc. I could use an unbiased model like linear regression but the error ends up being very high and I felt that the interpretation of coefficients would therefore be innaccurate.

Comment: @Ben  The error and the interpretation of the coefficients are two different things.  If all model assumptions are correct, the coefficients are an unbiased estimate of the effects.  It sounds like you're doing statistical inference so I would encourage you to focus on verifying the assumptions of a simple regression as opposed to using some sort of machine learning approach.